# Can blocked Python threads cause other threads to block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

When using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor to make web requests, all threads seem to wait when one blocks for a response.

From what I understand Python threads won't get assigned to separate cores like threads in C/C++, but I'm curious if this situation is a good application of them.

```
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    for item in items:
        executor.submit(make_request,item)
    executor.shutdown(wait=True)

    return


    def make_request(item):
        #make request using item info

        if worked:
            print("success")
        else:
            print("failed")

        return
```

For example if I use 5 workers, all 5 will make requests one after the other (seemingly quite faster than when using 1 worker), however when one request takes long or times out the others seem to stop and wait for it. I expected that if one waited 5 seconds for a response and the others already finished, the rest would keep making new requests and move on.

Am I misunderstanding how Python threads work? Or maybe I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor improperly.

Comment: Please post something we can actually run, that reproduces the problem when run. It doesn't have to be the whole program that prompted you to ask this question, as long as it satisfies those two criteria.

Comment: ...specifically, your question is about "blocked threads," but where is the code that blocks? It isn't shown in your example.